# Flutter - Stripe : type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>?' error in method_channel_stripe.dart:263

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments, flutter-stripe

It's my first post here.
I'm struggling with a Stripe integration in a Flutter project and can't find any other similar issue or problem on the web.
I'm using flutter Bloc and Stripe.

Once I run the function `await Stripe.instance.presentPaymentSheet();` and try to fake a payement with the credit card 42424 42424 42424 42424. I have the above error:

```
[VERBOSE-2:dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>?'
#0      MethodChannelStripe.presentPaymentSheet
method_channel_stripe.dart:263
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      Stripe.presentPaymentSheet
stripe.dart:517
<asynchronous suspension>
```

I'm creating the payment intent in my backend and everything seems to be fine with this part in my Stripe Dashboard

Here is a short reproduction of my code:

pubspec.yaml

```
  bloc: ^8.0.0
  flutter_bloc: ^8.0.0
  flutter_stripe: ^9.3.0
```

stripe_bloc.dart

```
class StripeBloc extends Bloc<StripeEvent, StripeState> {
  StripeBloc() : super(const StripeState()) {
    on<RequestedStripePaymentEvent>(_onRequestedStripePaymentEvent);
  }

  void _onRequestedStripePaymentEvent(RequestedStripePaymentEvent event,
      Emitter<StripeState> emit) async {
    try {
      final Map<String, dynamic>? paymentIntent = await createPaymentIntent();
      await Stripe.instance.initPaymentSheet(
          paymentSheetParameters: SetupPaymentSheetParameters(

        paymentIntentClientSecret: paymentIntent?['client_secret'],
      ));
      await Stripe.instance.presentPaymentSheet();
    } on StripeException catch (e) {
      if (e.error.code == FailureCode.Canceled) {}
      if (e.error.code == FailureCode.Failed ||
          e.error.code == FailureCode.Timeout) {
      }
    } finally {
    }
  }
}
```

stripe_api.dart

```
Future<Map<String, dynamic>?> createPaymentIntent() async {
  try {
    var response =
        await postAPIAuthenticated('path');
    return jsonDecode(response.body);
  } catch (err) {
    throw Exception(err);
  }
}
```

Hope guys could help me :) Thanks

I already try to make my code as minimal as possible.
I also try to call the stripe API directly in my front end and still get the same error so I think my backend is not involved in this

Comment: Didn't succeed to had Hi :) on top of my message. So Hello everyone :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the past 2 days, the problem has been reported numerous times on the GitHub repository of the flutter_stripe package:

https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe/issues/1344

It seems to be due to a problem with version 9.3.0. A downgrade to 9.2.2 solves the problem. For the rest, we'll probably have to wait for Stripe to resolve it internally.

Hope it helps you !

Comment: Thanks a lot Zlatan. Just saw the issue. Actually downgrading fixed the problem

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the error is version related.

An issues had just been raised on Github: https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe/issues/1344!

Answer (score 0):

The error means that your response is actually a list and not a map. In other words, the response is like `[ ... ]` and not `{ ... }`. Maybe the expected map is actually the first element in the list. If so this maybe can fix it:

```
Future<Map<String, dynamic>?> createPaymentIntent() async {
  try {
    var response =
        await postAPIAuthenticated('path');
    return jsonDecode(response.body)[0]; //notice I added [0] here
  } catch (err) {
    throw Exception(err);
  }
}
```

If this doesn't fix it I suggest you print the `response` to see what actual response you get and go from there

Comment: Hi @Ivo Thanks for your answer. I think the solution here is a bit more tricky. After double check my API response is actually a Map like response. Moreover everything goes right until `await Stripe.instance.presentPaymentSheet();` meaning initPayementSheet and my API response is correct since I have the right behaviour til here... well I guess

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to pubspec.yaml:

```
stripe_ios: ^9.3.1
```